# store the URL of an upload in filestack into a mysql database

Tags: php, filestack

I've recently signed up to filestack, and I am finding it a bit difficult to understand their documentation.

I've added the javaascript plugin on to my website. However I am just wondering if you can actually store the URL of the uploaded file into a mysql database?

Comment: You can store anything (data related) in a MySQL database .. I am not understanding the question.  Are you asking **how** to store the uploaded URL into a database?

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to see if it was possible, but also find out how to do it. So ive added the filestack / filepicker JS code on to mysite. Just not sure what the next step is to actually get the URL of the file the person just uploaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Just not sure what the next step is to actually get the URL of the
>   file the person just uploaded

Please take a look at this example: https://jsfiddle.net/1fLjbrwr/1/

```
client.pick({
  accept: 'image/*',
}).then(function(result) {
  // file url (plus mimetype, size and more)
  // can be found inside the result object
  console.log(result);
  console.log("File url: " + result.filesUploaded[0].url);
});
```

When file is uploaded, you can use a callback function to handle the response.

You can also use one of built-in callback functions that are called at various points during the upload process (docs available here: https://www.filestack.com/docs/javascript-api/pick-v3):

```
client.pick({
  accept: 'image/*',
  onFileUploadFinished: function(file) {
    // this will be called when file is uploaded
    console.log(file);
  }
})
```